# StackExchange NetGain vs Node.js WS websocket server performance

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket

I'm primarily a C#/.NET developer who needs to write a relatively simple but high-performance & stable websocket server. Currently, it looks like the only official platform for websocket related work from Microsoft is SignalR. However, for my needs, it adds too much overhead.

One other option that looks appealing is StackExchange's NetGain library, however, there doesn't seem to be much information out there other than the github page. There isn't even a question/answer related to that library on stackoverflow. I did find a twitter post by someone at stackexchange showing NetGain serving 500K concurrent sessions BUT those were spread across several machines. In contrast, WS module on Node.js can handle 550K on a single server.

Is WS module on Node.js more efficient than NetGain? For simple NetGain based websocket servers how many concurrent connections can I have on a single quad core based machine? I'd really like to use NetGain and stay with C# because I'm still learning Node.js, however, If there is a big performance difference than I'd rather go with Node.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately a blanket which is better in regards to performance is not the right question.

At [Ably](https://www.ably.io), we handle millions of websocket connections with very little overhead because simply keeping a connection open requires very little work. When we designed our frontend servers which terminate and hold open WebSocket connections, we looked at a few things:

- Do the WS connections need a heartbeat, and if so, how frequently? Do we rely solely on TCP/IP to detect connections going away, or do we improve the reliability of abrupt disconnection detection with heartbeats? We needed the latter so that we could provide more accurate [presence / device awareness](https://www.ably.io/documentation/realtime/presence), so that adds a lot of overhead. If for example we have 100k connections on a single box and send a heartbeat every 10 seconds, that is 10k heartbeats sent and received per second, so 20k frames of data per second.
- What is the expected rate of work for each connection. We assume connection usage will vary immensely, but you do need to come up with a rough estimate of work expected per connection. We assumed an average of 1 message per second per connection broadcasted, and 10 messages per minute received. So once again if you assume 100k connections, that’s 100k messages broadcasted per second plus 16k messages received plus approx 16k ACKs sent.
- How frequently do connections drop and reconnect and how much work is needed each time a new connection comes in. For example, with you had 100k connections and expected each one to reconnect every 10 minutes, that’s 166 new connections per second. Each new connection requires handshakes, authentication, HTTP upgrades, so let’s assume that’s the equivalent of roughly 20 operations in total to establish a connection or 3,320 per second.
- Are your terminating TLS, if so, [all bets are off](http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/19257368025/how-elastic-are-amazon-elastic-load-balancers).
  So assuming all of above for 100k connections, we can expect roughly 20k heartbeat operations + 100k message broadcasts + 32k message received incl. ACK + 3.3k connection terminations = 155k operations per second.

But that’s not accounting for peaks and troughs, it is not unrealistic to expect your sustained peaks (over a period of say 1 minute) to exceed your average by 3–4x, so that’s roughly 600k operations per second.

**Conclusion**

Talking about how many connections a WS library can hold open is not that important. Processing messages, handling auth, dealing with failures and communicating with other systems is what is probably going to use up all your resources, so start from there if you want to estimate what a beefy box can do.

Matt, co-founder, [Ably - simply better realtime](https://www.ably.io)

Comment: Interesting Analysis. After doing some more digging on NetGain, I've found that it doesn't support SSL and they have no plans of adding SSL support anytime soon. WS seems to be the only option at this point.

Comment: If you can offload your TLS termination to Load Balancers, I highly recommend it, see http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/19257368025/how-elastic-are-amazon-elastic-load-balancers